# Dictionary - inherited classes

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a (hopefully) simple question:

I have some classes:

```
class Foo
class Foo1 : Foo
class Foo2 : Foo
```

I have two dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<int, Foo1> dic1 

Dictionary<int, Foo2> dic2
```

And I have a method:

```
private static int Method(Dictionary<int, Foo>)
```

and a method call:

```
Method(dic1);
```

but now I get the error that I can't convert `Dictionary<int, Foo1>` to `Dictionary<int, Foo>`.

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generics, with a constraint of `Foo` should do it

```
public class Foo { }
public class Foo1 : Foo { }
public class Foo2 : Foo { }

public class SomeClass
{    
   public static int Method<T>(Dictionary<int, T> dict) where T : Foo
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Constraints on type parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)

> Constraints inform the compiler about the capabilities a type argument
>   must have. Without any constraints, the type argument could be any
>   type. The compiler can only assume the members of Object, which is the
>   ultimate base class for any .NET type.
>
> ...
>
> By constraining the type parameter, you increase the number of
>   allowable operations and method calls to those supported by the
>   constraining type and all types in its inheritance hierarchy. When you
>   design generic classes or methods, if you will be performing any
>   operation on the generic members beyond simple assignment or calling
>   any methods not supported by System.Object, you will have to apply
>   constraints to the type parameter.
>
> ...
>
> For example, the base class constraint tells the compiler that only
>   objects of this type or derived from this type will be used as type
>   arguments. Once the compiler has this guarantee, it can allow methods
>   of that type to be called in the generic class.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from limiting the type of the Dictionary, there are two features to support this: Covariance and Contravariance.

They allow you to treat a collection of a more/less derived type, like one of another type. So a `Foo1[]` could be assigned to a `Foo[]`, same way you would assign a `Foo1` to a `Foo` variable.

Here is the whole offocial article on the mater:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/